# How find and count file types

Tags: shell, sorting, count, find

How do you use the `find` command to count by file type but have it exclude a folder01 with in the directory searching?
This is the command I have:

```
find . -not -path "./folder1/*” type f |
grep -o ".[^.]\+$" |
sort | uniq -c
```

The output I would like is for example

```
5 jpg
2 gif
```

Comment: You have a typo that leads to an error `find: paths must precede expression: \`type'`. Therefore, use `-type`.

Comment: Is this how you change the command "find . –type -f -not -path "./folder1/*” | grep -o ".[^.]+$" | sort | uniq -c"

Answer (score 0):

The immediate problem here, as already pointed out in comments, is that you need a dash before `-type`:

```
find . -not -path "./folder1/*” -type f
```

But you can easily avoid the unnecessary `grep`; the `find` command itself is quite good at specifying conditions on what you want to find.

```
find . -not -path "./folder1/*” -name '*.*' -type f |
sort | uniq -c
```